# What is the purpose of Angular animations?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I've been wondering for some time now **why should I use Angular animations over CSS animations**. I see few areas one might consider before using them:

---

### Performance

In the first step I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949262/angular-2-animation-vs-css-animation-when-to-use-what) which deals only with performace side of things. The accepted answer is not satisfying for me because it states that *one should use CSS animations wherever possible so that optimizations like running the animations in separate thread can apply*. This doesn't seem to be true, because [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations#overview) states

> Angular animations are **built on top of the standard Web Animations API** and run natively on browsers that support it.

(emphasis mine)

And when we look at [Web Animations API Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations/#introduction) we see that the same optimizations can apply to Web Animations as to CSS specified in sheets.

> While it is possible to use ECMAScript to perform animation using requestAnimationFrame [HTML], such animations behave differently to declarative animation in terms of how they are represented in the CSS cascade and the performance optimizations that are possible such as performing the animation on a separate thread. **Using the Web Animations** programming interface, it is **possible to create animations** from script **that have the same behavior and performance characteristics as declarative animations**.

(emphasis mine again)

Apart from some browsers like IE don't support Web Animations, **is there any reason to use either CSS declarations over Angular animations or vice versa?** I see them as exchangeable performace-wise.

---

### More control over the animations

This might look as an argument for Angular animations, because you can [pause animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713488/pause-angular-animations) or use JS variables with it etc., but the same is true while using eg. CSS `animation-play-state: pause` or using **CSS variables** specified in JS, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Values_in_JavaScript).

Now I can see it might be inconvenient to set the CSS variables in JS code, but the same is true while using Angular animations. These are typically declared in `@Component` `animations` field and don't have, except for via the animation state data bound property, access to instance fields (if you don't create your animation via `AnimationBuilder` of course, which btw is also not very convenient or beautiful either).

Other point is, with Web Animations API it is possible to [inspect, debug or test](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations/#use-cases) the animations, but I don't see how this is possible with Angular animations. If it is, could you please show me how? If it isn't, I really **don't see any advantage of using Angular animations over CSS ones for the sake of control either**.

---

### Cleaner code

I've read for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API#Meet_the_Web_Animations_API) a paragraph stating that separating animations from "normal" styles is actually separation of behaviour and presentation. **Is really declaring animations in styles sheets mixing those responsibilities?** I saw that always the other way, especially looking at CSS rules in the `@Component` animations gave me a feeling of having CSS declarations on one too many places.

---

#### So how is it with Angular animations?

- Is it just a convenience utility to extract animations away from the rest of the styles, or does it bring anything worthy feature-wise?
- Does a usage of Angular animations pay off only in special cases or is it a convention a team chooses to go all the way with it?

I would love to here about tangible advantages of using Angular animations. Thanks guys upfront!

Comment: Do you know about Angular nested animations, staged animations, and state transitions? And this becomes quite complicated with simple web animations. This is... exactly what you want to build animated web apps. Angular animations are meant to reach Android-like animations level.

Comment: What I've found quite addicting about angular animations is that they can be easily reused in different platforms (example: you may use the exact same animation in different frameworks like plain angular 2 (web app), ionic 3, nativescript, electron). Other than that, be aware that you can nest animations, define them as transition animations... And you can even modularize them.

Comment: Plus I will add, the goal of a framework, and everything that comes with it is to increase your productivity.

Comment: @Ploppy I guess state transitions is what triggers the animation. One binds the animation trigger to element and field variable and change in this variable triggers the animation if it matches the state. Didn't here about nested or staged animations though.

Comment: I would interpret "*run natively on browsers that support it*" as falling back to a less optimised polyfill on browsers that don't support web animations.

Comment: @briosheje sounds good, do you have any link to explanation on nested animations? And what do you mean by transition animations, do you mean equivalent of CSS transitions?

Comment: @Ploppy that's exactly what I am trying to find out, how do Angular animations increase productivity.

Comment: @DanMacák : about transitions, you can easily define animation states and transition **between** states. Other than that, you can set animation states from components / services directly and track animation start and end events (along with other relevant stuff). About "nested" animations, I mean that you can run parallel / serial animation sets programmatically (check this post addressing the "common" issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598685/run-multiple-query-animations-in-parallel).

Comment: @briosheje where can I get these events? I will check that link out, thank you!

Comment: @DanMacák : https://angular.io/guide/animations#animation-callbacks . Also, another point you may like: https://angular.io/guide/animations#automatic-property-calculation

Comment: @briosheje I will have a look, thank you!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

So I did some research and although I didn't find any argument for nor against Angular animations performance-wise (as already stated in the question above), **there are very good arguments to use Angular animations feature-wise** which should be good enough for purists who want to have CSS only in sheets, at least in certain cases.

Let me list some useful features where each alone makes a convincing case for Angular animations. Most of them can be found in [Angular animations documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations#animations):

1. **Transition styles** - these styles are only applied during transition from one state to another - only while an element is being animated, and one uses them like this:

   ```
   transition('stateA => stateB', [style({...}), animate(100)])
   ```

   Trying to do the same with CSS only might not be as expressive in terms of which previous state led to the next. And it can be outright clunky if the animation has to differ based on the initial state but the end state is the same.
2. The **`void`** state together with **`:enter`** and **`:leave`** aliases ([void documentation](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#void-state), [:leave and :enter documentation](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases)) - **Let you animate elements being added or removed from the DOM.**

   ```
   transition('stateA => void', animate(...))
   ```

   This is very cool because previously, although it was easy enough to animate the addition, the removal was more complicated and required to trigger animation, wait till its end and only after that remove the element from the DOM, all with JS.
3. **Automatic property calculation** `'*'` ([documentation](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#automatic-property-calculation-with-wildcards)) - Allows for performing traditionally difficult animations like [height transitions for elements with dynamic height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css). This problem required either to set fixed height on element (inflexible), use max-height with tuned transition function (not perfect) or query element's height with JS (potentially causing unnecessary reflows). But now with Angular it is as easy as this:

   ```
   trigger('collapsible', [
     state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
     state('collapsed', style({ height: '0' })),
     transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate(100))
   ])
   ```

   And the animation is smooth and "complete" because the *actual* height of the element is used for the transition.
4. **Animation callbacks** ([documentation](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks)) - this is something that wasn't possible with CSS animations (if not maybe emulated with `setTimeout`) and is handy eg. for debugging.
5. Unlike stated in the question, **it is actually possible to use instance fields as params in Angular animations**, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966673/parameter-in-to-animation-angular2). I find it much easier to use than manipulating CSS variables through DOM API as shown [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Values_in_JavaScript), not mentioning the limited support in some browsers.

If you need any of the features listed above, Angular can be a better tool for the task. Also when there is many animations to manage in a component, and this is just my personal opinion, I find it easier to organize animations the Angular way than have them in sheets, where it is harder too see the relationships between them and various element states.

Comment: I am sold! Thank you for the research and for the explanations. Point # 2 and 4 its been a pain to develop using pure CSS and angular solve it in a very elegant way.

Comment: I've seen some pretty bad performance in other browsers than chrome.  Even a slide animation starts to drop frames due to ngOnInit firing up.  I've looked high and low for alternatives to use GSAP or just straight CSS and I can't come up with options.  Seems like you get locked into route animations with embedded CSS styling with TypeScript.  Suspect its polyfill based code causing the issue.  Seems to have a lot of processing sucking up rendering resulting in jank.

Comment: Nevermind, this tutorial used left/right to animate vs translateX.  That created the jank.  I also notice if you use a few animations they all seem to trigger in the background so be careful with that too.  Seems like it would be smarter to have a single trigger and route to the appropriate animation by passing data thru instead of having countless triggers for all the pop, slide, fade, dissolve etc transitions.